# Why when I try to execute a program as normal user I get denied, and when I execute it with sudo I get "Not Found"

Tags: bash, sudo, root

In order to execute mysqlbackup I have to execute it as root.

Here's the example when I execute it as normal user:

```
mysqlbackup --compress --user=root --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --backup-dir=/home/user/backup backup
MySQL Enterprise Backup version 3.12.2 Linux-2.6.32-400.37.11.el6uek.i686-i686 [2016/01/19] 
Copyright (c) 2003, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

 mysqlbackup: INFO: Starting with following command line ...
 mysqlbackup --compress --user=root --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
        --backup-dir=/home/user/backup backup 

 mysqlbackup: INFO: 
 mysqlbackup: INFO: MySQL server version is '5.5.44-MariaDB'.
 mysqlbackup: INFO: Got some server configuration information from running server.

IMPORTANT: Please check that mysqlbackup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful 'backup' run mysqlbackup
           prints "mysqlbackup completed OK!".

160226 08:30:02 mysqlbackup: INFO: MEB logfile created at /home/user/backup/meta/MEB_2016-02-26.08-30-02_compress_backup.log

 mysqlbackup: ERROR: Opening of file /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 failed. Error code: 13, Permission denied
```

which leads to Permission denied, so I tried to execute it with sudo and I get this:

```
 sudo mysqlbackup
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: mysqlbackup: command not found
```

But when I execute it as a root I don't have any problems...

my user is inside of the sudoers file just so you know and I can also execute other commands with sudo with no problems, but in this case my question is, why I can't execute it with sudo and how I can be able to execute it without recurring to sudo -i to get the root environment?

**Note**:
They both have the same $PATH

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
[root@localhost ~]# exit
[user@localhost backup]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
```

Comment: sudo creates a minimal operating environment, in which the `PATH` variable doesn't contain as many directories as, when you login as root in an interactive session. You need to specify the path to  `mysqlbackup` executable explicitly, to overcome this hurdle. While logged in as root, run `which mysqlbackup` to get the full path name if need be

Comment: This is potentially configuration-specific.  You should say what distribution and version you are using.

Comment: @sourcejedi Centos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason that you're backup is failing as a normal user is because the `libdata` file that `mysqlbackup` is attempting to copy/backup is owned by a different user (more than likely, 'mysql') or a privileged user. So, running `mysqlbackup` as an elevated user is probably the right choice here as you're attempting to do.

I surmise that the reason you aren't able to find `mysqlbackup` as an elevated user is your `PATH` environment not being set properly or set at all. Am I right to assume that you can't do something like:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqldump --compr....
```

If you can then just make sure to run the command with the absolute path to `mysqldump`. If that doesn't work because of how `sudo` is configured, then you'll need to try a different tactic like.

```
PATH=/usr/bin sudo mysqlbackup --compress ...
```

Now if that works, great. However, it's not very nice for future command line use. You could create an `alias` to run `mysqlbackup` in the future so that you don't need to specify the PATH in the command line for future use:

For bash:

(for other shells like `zsh`, you'll need to read the docs on how to set an alias)

```
echo 'alias mysqlbackup="PATH=/usr/bin sudo mysqlbackup"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

...which could be invoked, after sourcing the `.bashrc` file (logout and login is sufficient, or sourcing the file IE `. ~/.bashrc`), in the future by simply running:

```
mysqlbackup --compress...
```

Let's say none of that works, though. You'll probably need to get the administrator of the machine to change your sudo permissions for `mysqlbackup` to either include the proper PATH or to specify an absolute path to `mysqlbackup` in the sudoers file for your ability to call it from the shell when executing `sudo`.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `secure_path` is set in /etc/sudoers.  The path shown by `which mysqlbackup` is not included there, but it is shown in `echo $PATH` when run as your user or from a root login, right?  It does seem odd though.